# nth-child first-child not working

Tags: css, css-selectors

trying to get the nth-child/first-child working
on the first label within the form below
but can't get it right

At the moment I'm using

```
form label {
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin:0 auto;
    color:#FFF;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding:40px 0 10px;
    font-weight: normal!important;
}
label:first-child {
        padding-top:0;
    }
```

but have used

```
form code div.field span.lspan label:nth-of-type(1)  
form code div.field span.lspan label:first-child  
.lspan label:first-child  
form label:first-child
```

they set all labels in the form to padding 0

```
    <form method="POST" action="" class="">
    <div class="field">
    <span class="lspan"><label for="sender_name">Name</label></span>
    <span class="inspan"><input class="hinput" type="text" name="sender_name" value=""></span>
       </div>
    <div class="field">
      <span class="lspan"><label for="sender_name">Email</label></span><span class="inspan">         <input class="hinput" type="text" name="email" value=""> </span></div>
    <div class="field">
      <span class="lspan"><label for="subject">Subject</label></span><span class="inspan"><input class="hinput" type="text" name="subject" value=""></span></div>
    <div class="field">
     <span class="lspan"><label for="sender_name">Message</label></span><span class="inspan">    <textarea class="htextarea" name="message"></textarea></span></div>
<div class="field">
        </div>
    <div class="field" style="margin-top:15px">

     <input type = "submit"  class="csubmit" name = "submit" value="Submit" style="" />
                </div>
      </form>
```

Thanks

Roy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the `<label>` tags in your code are a `first-child` of their respective `<span>` element.

If you only want to target the first appearance of a `<label>` in your code use this:

```
form div:first-child label {
  padding: 0;
}
```

This will target any label within the `<div>` element, that is the `first-child` of the form.

Remember, that you can use `:first-child` on any subselektor and not just on the outermost right!